# What does "Do you haz teh codez?" mean?

Tags: pronunciation

There is a banner in StackOverflow pointing to the careers website (programmers):

> Do you haz teh codez?

My questions about the sentence/question are:

- What's the question in plain English?
- Why do they write it like that?
- Is it like a word game?
- How should I read it in terms of pronunciation?

  [image: Do you haz teh codez?]

Comment: It's called lolspeak: http://speaklolspeak.com/

Comment: I've always felt it was dangerously close to mocking programmers whose English is poor. When we see poor spelling, it's difficult (and dangerous) to judge whether the writer has limited English,or  is being careless and thoughtless, or isusing a dialect of English popular among their particular peer group.

Comment: I doubt it's intentionally mocking people with poor English skills. My nephew, born and raised in Los Angeles by English speaking parents, well into his mid 20s he rarely wrote a full correct English sentence. I assume he could have but that his culture of friends was of chat for things like MSN Messenger (popular at the time). Also @Gilead link is out of date but [this works](https://www.google.com/search?q=lolspeak)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Literal translation is "Do you have the code?" but what is implied is "Please can you write my application for me?" or "Please solve my problem so I don't have to put any effort in."

It is written like that as a mockery of people who ask questions on Stack Overflow, and other such websites, where their question is a thinly veiled, or completely unveiled, attempt to get someone to do their work for them. So the questioner won't have even have tried to solve their problem and will possibly be asking for an entire software application to be written.

I'm not sure what you mean by "Is there like a word game?" If you mean *is this like a word game* then not really, it's just a joke.

It should be pronounced "Do you haz (as in Mazda) teh (as in meh) codes?" and in IPA: /duːjuːhæztɛkəʊdz/.

For an example of the type of thing this is mocking: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/plz-email-me-teh-codez.aspx

Comment: You might be surprised to learn that in some places the first syllable of *Mazda* rhymes with *jazz* and in other places it rhymes with *ahs* (as in “oohs and ahs”)

Comment: I think it is very wrong to construe this ad as mocking.  No, the appeal of the ad, the hook, is that is that it is appealing to a shared culture amongst programmers, who spend alot of the Internet and have been near the genesis of many prominent Internet trends and memes.  It's saying, "We [StackOverflow management] KNOW you, we get your culture, we're part of it, so we know the kind of job you're looking for -- take some time and check out this service we're trying to sell."

Comment: @Billare: I disagree. There is no way it can be anything *but* a send up of the people that ask those type of questions, since that is what the phrase relates to, it doesn't relate to anything else. I agree that the SO guys are trying to tap into the culture of the users of the site.

Comment: @nohat I thought that "jazz" and "ahs" rhymed! (I suppose "ahs" might be a bit longer but...)

Comment: I think obvious typos are meant to highlight their zero effort spent on even formulating the question, i.e.: "I can't be bothered to check my typos, but you give me the full solution!"

Comment: @nohat I would pronounce *ahs*, *haz* and the first syllable of *mazda* in the same way. I'm interested in who pronounces differently and why?

Comment: @DarrenH there are two "A" vowels: A as in 'TRAP' (IPA /æ/) and A as in 'WASH' (IPA /ɑ/). For most American English speakers, "ahs"(like when the dentist says "Say 'AH'") and "Mazda" have /ɑ/ as the first vowel, and "has" (and variant spelling "haz") would have /æ/ as the first vowel. In American English the first syllable of "Mazda" does *not* rhyme with "has" and "jazz". It rhymes with "Oz" and the first syllable of "positive" and "Cosby".

Comment: I think there's one too many 'have's" in: `the questioner won't have even have tried to solve` Maybe *"....won't even have tried....*"

Comment: Note that the usage of bad grammar refers to the [LOLCats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUoSXLIQ4uk), where the captions followed this pattern of bad grammar. "I can has cheezburger?" is the name of the website that popularized it.

Answer (score 9):

So, to break it down:

haz=have
teh=the
codez=codes

So it means *Do you have the codes?* or in a bit more sensible form considering the context *Are you able to code?* (Code here meaning to write code, or program)

These are variations from internet memes (google lolcats, if you dare) that have become mainstream (usually in a tongue-in-cheek way).  I'll stress this is NOT standard English.

Presumably the banner is done that way to catch someone's attention by avoiding a more standard (and therefore less engaging) phrase.  It also may indicate that they're more tied into to internet/programming culture which has a history of using intentionally obfuscated terms/spellings/etc. to set them apart and to act as a shibboleth.

As for the pronunciation, you can pretty much just read it phonetically, as the alterations are intended to be applied to the pronunciation as much as the spelling.

Comment: I don't think I'd interpret "do you have the codes" as "are you able to code".

Comment: @Martha - because of the context (a link to a jobs section on StackOverflow, a programming website) I'm fairly sure that's what was intended.  It can certainly be used in the sense Matt describes, but I'm not sure why a banner ad on a site would be posted to make fun of people using the site.

Comment: I think they're poking fun at the users of the site who don't get how it's meant to work, and by doing so attracting the attention of the users who use it in the intended way. They want the users that "get it" to use the careers site, and I would guess they probably don't want those that don't get it to be posting their resumes. It's all supposition until the marketing team weigh in!

Comment: I also think it is a funny way of suggesting that upper management and HR who might hire the programmers are the ones who are looking for someone to do their work for them.

Comment: So, any explanation for the downvote?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, it means "do you have the code" ie.

"**are you capable of writing quality code** (ie, since it's a career ad you're reading, are you a programmer looking for work) **and are you [geek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geek) enough** (since it's an ad you're reading, in the positive sense of the word, of course) **to** understand and like geekish talk like this (which implies that you'd **fit a similarly geek company of computer experts** well)?"

They write it like that because it's supposed to be cool and to match the target audience's usage.

As for a word game being there - no, there's none imo, apart from the above.

For the pronunciation, [go here and click listen](http://translate.google.com/translate_t?hl=&ie=UTF-8&text=Do+you+haz+teh+codez+%3F&sl=en&tl=en#). ;) (That's half a joke, sure. But I'm fairly sure the majority of... errr... geeks would get and like it.)

Comment: Yes, exactly.  It appeals simultaneously to programmers' competitive qualities and their shared culture.